# Reading FederationMetadata.xml in golang using http

Tags: xml, http, go

I am trying to get the  FederationMetadata.xml  using http in golan using the following way.

```
response, err := client.Get("https://domainc.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml").
```

The response body comes back as all numeric values(see below) and not in XML format. But I am able to download this file  from chrome as an xml file.

```
61 34 117 114 110 58 111 97 115 105 115 58 110 97 109 101 115 58
116 99 58 83 65 77 76 58 50 46 48 58 97 115 115 101 114 116 105 111
110 34 47 62 60 65 116 116 114 105 98 117 116 101 32 78 97 109 101
61 34 104 116 116 112 58 47 47 115 99 104 101 109 97 115 46 109
105 99 114 111 115 111 102 116 46 99 111 109 47 50 48 49 50 47 48
49 47 114 101 113 117 101 115 116 99 111 110 116 101 120 116 47 99 10
```

Code:

```
tr := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
response, err := client.Get("https://domainc.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml")
if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
} else {
    defer response.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(response.Body)
    responseXML, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(responseXML)
}
```

Comment: Please chow an example of what you're doing. This looks like you're printing a `[]byte` from a portion of the response.

Comment: I am printing the response.body. Here is my code:                                    
tr := &http.Transport{
 TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
response, err := client.Get("https://domainc.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml")
if err != nil {
 os.Exit(1)
} else {
 defer response.Body.Close()
 fmt.Println(response.Body)
 responseXML, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("%s", err)
  os.Exit(1)
 }
 fmt.Println(responseXML)
}

Comment: Try to edit the question and add some code. In the current form it impossible for anyone to know exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Please put your code into the question and format it properly. It's very hard to read in a comment (esp. since it can't be parsed properly).

Comment: Thank you @AlexatNet for editing it.

Comment: Just DIY next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`responseXML` is slice of bytes (a `[]byte`).

You must convert it to a string to print it, either with:

```
fmt.Println(string(responseXML))
```

or via `%s` in a Printf format string:

```
fmt.Printf("This is the response: \n%s\n", responseXML)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead `fmt.Println(response.Body)` use `fmt.Println(string(response.Body))`, which should print:

```
... ="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/c ...
```